# How to pass dynamic parameter to dataProvider method in testNG

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi, testng

I am trying to load data from an Excel file into my testing framework by dynamically entering the name of the sheet the data is getting extracted from, reusing the existing data provider this way.

Example: I am loading data from the LoginCredentials sheet, which represents the data for a successful login test. 
The second test is a failed login test which loads data from the InvalidLoginCredentials sheet.
The third test pulls data from a third sheet UserInformation etc. 
The udemy course I was following did not really cover this topic and I feel like the actual implementation of the whole thing is not the best either, but I just went with it since it is my first time dealing with Selenium and Excel.

The main issue seems to be sending this sheet name parameter to the getData method which is the data provider. For some reason, I am thinking that the solution is probably very simple just that I cannot wrap my head around it.

I have tried the XML parameter attribute but it does not solve my issue. I want to send this parameter dynamically depending on the test.

I have tried using the @Parameters annotation both on my test method and on the data provider method, but that doesn't work either. The problem with putting it on the test method is because I assume the dataprovider annotation is attempting to retrieve String sheetName from the Excel file as well and my tests wont even run.

Using it on the data provider method itself is not an option because of the fact I have to make as many data provider methods as parameters sent (which then ruins the whole point of reusing my existing dataProvider).

Method for fetching data from excel file

```
public Object[][] testData(String excelPath, String sheetName) {

        Object[][] data = null;

        try {
            ExcelUtil excelUtil = new ExcelUtil(excelPath, sheetName);

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelPath);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
            int rowCount = excelUtil.getRowCount();
            int colCount = excelUtil.getColCount();

            data = new Object[rowCount - 1][colCount];

            for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {

                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {

                    Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                        case STRING:
                            data[i - 1][j] = excelUtil.getCellDataString(i, j);
                            break;


                        case NUMERIC:
                            data[i - 1][j] = String.valueOf(excelUtil.getCellDataNumeric(i, j));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while loading data from Excel file: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return data;
    }
```

The dataProvider method itself

```
 @DataProvider(name = "TeamoLoginData")
    public Object[][] getData(){
        String excelPath = "src/main/java/apps/teamo/testdata/Book 1.xlsx";
        return testData(excelPath, "LoginCredentials");
    }
```

Test method:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "TeamoLoginData", dataProviderClass = ExcelDataProvider.class)
    public void loginSuccessful(Method method, String username, String password) {

        ExtentTestManager.startTest(methodName, "Successful login");
        TeamoLoginPage teamoLoginPage = new TeamoLoginPage(getDriver());
        TeamoHomePage teamoHomePage = new TeamoHomePage(getDriver());

            getDriver().get(PropertyManager.getInstance().getBaseURL());
            teamoLoginPage.enterUsername(username);
            teamoLoginPage.enterPassword(password);

            teamoLoginPage.signIn();

            Assert.assertTrue(teamoHomePage.changeLogIsDisplayed());
    }
```

Is there a way to pass a string with the sheet name somewhere as a parameter so that the tests get relevant information?

Comment: quick  question: in order to keep that simple - wouldnt You consider to separate each sheet You need into separate .xls files which You may explicitly define in code?

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, but then again thought that there might be too many .xls files in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPTION A:**

I'd recommend to look towards `ITestContext`  as it've been [described here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/45316725/1546574).

Providing two `@Test` methods below:
first one test method setting the attribute (=sheet name) , 
and second one @Test  method (depending on the first one)- is driven by a dataprovider that is consuming data from the sheet we've specified.

```
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DemoTestClass {

    @Test
    public void testTabnameSetting() {
        //Simulating toggling between multiple flows.
        String tabName = "LoginCredentials";
        Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().setAttribute("sheetName", tabName);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "testTabnameSetting", dataProvider = "getData")
    public void loginSuccess(String username, String pass) {
        //test method logic goes here. .....


    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData(ITestContext context) {
        String sheetNameToParse = context.getAttribute("sheetName").toString();

        String excelPath = "src/main/java/apps/teamo/testdata/Book 1.xlsx";
        return testData(excelPath, sheetNameToParse);
    }
}
```

============

**Option B:**
You may defined different tests (in suite) for different purposes like

```
public class DemoTestClass {
@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
public void   testSheetA(String username, String pass){
....}

@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
public void
    testSheetB(String username, String pass){...}

@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
public void
    testSheetC(String username, String pass){....}

}
```

And other option - is just to re-organized Your dataprovider that will be analyzing test name and therefore -suppliying for the test appropriate sheet name:

```
@DataProvider
public  Object[][] getData(ITestNGMethod testContext)
{
    String excelPath = "src/main/java/apps/teamo/testdata/Book 1.xlsx";
    if(testContext.getMethodName().equals("testSheetA"))
    {
        return testData(excelPath, "sheetA");
    }
    else if(testContext.getMethodName().equals("testSheetB"))
    {

        return testData(excelPath, "sheetB");
    }
    .....

}
```

Here in this article I've explained how [to set-up selenium java maven testNG project](https://experitest.com/blog-cat/testng_framework_maven/) from scratch.

Hope this be helpful for You.
Kind regards,

Comment: Thank you very much, the third option seemed the easiest one and I'll be using that solution.